# React: How to get variable from URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes

I'm building an application that needs to load a "workspace" from the database based on the slug provided in the URL. My URL structure is `/app/<workspace slug>/<workspace view>`. Currently there are 3 views for each workspace: Map, List and Settings. I need to get the value of the `<workspace slug>` from the URL in order to load the correct workspace from the database. Also I need to return an error if the workspace is not found.

I'm pretty new to React so I may not currently be following best practices.

**My Routing**

Currently I'm routing to each workspace view by looping through each workspace and creating a route for each of the 3 views in `App.js`:

```
renderContent() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={NetworkMap} exact />
              {this.state.workspaces.map(function(workspace, index){ // Map View Routes
                return (
                  <Route path={"/app/" + workspace.slug + "/map"} render={(props) => <Workspace {...props} workspace={workspace} component={Map} />} />
                );
              })}
              {this.state.workspaces.map(function(workspace, index){ // List View Routes
                return (
                  <Route path={"/app/" + workspace.slug + "/list"} render={(props) => <Workspace {...props} workspace={workspace} component={List} />} />
                );
              })}
              {this.state.workspaces.map(function(workspace, index){ // Settings View Routes
                return (
                  <Route path={"/app/" + workspace.slug + "/settings"} render={(props) => <Workspace {...props} workspace={workspace} component={WorkspaceSettings} />} />
                );
              })}
            <Route component={Error} />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

**My Links**

```
{props.workspaces.map(function(workspace, index){
  return (<Link key={index} to={"/app/" + workspace.slug + "/map"} className="dropdown-item cursor-pointer">{workspace.name}</Link>);
})}
```

**My Index.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

I've tried changing `workspace.slug` to `:slug` in the Route's path which I thought should make it appear in props but I can't seem to get it working properly:

```
{this.state.workspaces.map(function(workspace, index){
  return (
    <Route path={"/app/:slug/map"} render={(props) => <Workspace {...props} workspace={workspace} component={Map} />} />
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

Components rendered via the `render` prop will also be passed some route props, specifically, `match` is the one you want. From there `props.match.params.slug` will be the slug value you want

```
{this.state.workspaces.map(function(workspace, index){
  return (
    <Route
      path="/app/:slug/map"
      render={props => (
        <Workspace
          {...props}
          workspace={workspace}
          component={Map}
          slug={props.match.params.slug}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
})}
```

`match` can also be access within the component `Workspace` via the spread in `props`. If `Workspace` is a functional component, react-router-dom also has a [`useParams`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sounds like the right direction, however this is in my App.js component, and using `this.props.match.params.slug` gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

Comment: Am I missing an import statement perhaps?

Comment: @Brack No, these are [`route props`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) that any `Route` passes to anything rendered by the `render` prop. Mind sharing what your `Router` code looks like in `App.js`?

Comment: Eh, sorry, I guess I assumed you were using react-router-dom. What navigation are you using?

Comment: I updated the router section to include all my routing code. I am using react-router-dom `import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"`

Comment: Yeah, `component`, `render`, and `children` props of a `Route` component all receive route props `match`, `location`, and `history`. I should note though, that within the `render` prop is a functional component, so no `this` to call on, it's just `props.match`.

Comment: I had made an error when pasting the solution I believe.